# how does Postgres handle timezone comparison?

Tags: postgresql, time

Seeking help understanding Postgres timezone conversion and comparison

#### query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/79009

```
SELECT
    now()
    , ( now() at time zone 'AEDT' ) AS now_AEDT
    , ( ( now() at time zone 'AEDT' ) at time zone 'AEDT' ) AS now_AEDT_AEDT
    , ( now() at time zone 'UTC' ) + interval '1' second
      > ( now() at time zone 'AEDT' ) AS should_be_true
```

#### Result

```
now            : 2021-07-30T01:03:10.707834Z (i assume system is UTC?)
now_AEDT       : 2021-07-30T12:03:10.707834Z
now_AEDT_AEDT  : 2021-07-30T01:03:10.707834Z (why is this different?) 
should_be_true : false                       (after adding a second; this should be true, no?)
```

#### questions / confusions

1. why does double-setting the timezone change the time? (now_AEDT_AEDT)
2. how are timestamps with timezones handled in comparison? It seems the zone is ignored and just the values are compared?

Comment: sqlfiddle is running some hacked-up version of PostgreSQL.  The real PostgreSQL doesn't produce those results.

Comment: It does in my postgres, I think the key is when your server timezone is different than the zone in the query, then you see this behavior

Comment: If I set my timezone to "UTC" or "Zulu", then I get '+00' not 'Z' as the timezone signifier for the 1st and 3rd result, and I get no timezone signifier at all for the 2nd result.  Do you really get 'Z' as the signifier for the all three of those on your own installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"at time zone" does opposite things when applied to timestamptz versus a timestamp.  So applying it twice in a row just gives you back the original.  First it does something, then it undoes it.

When applied to timestamptz, it converts the time to look like what it would be expressed as in the indicated time zone, and datatypes it as a timestamp without timezone (except in sqlfiddle, where it seems to do something slightly different, but without changing the overall effect).  When applied to a timestamp without timezone, it assumes that that time expressed was already in the indicated time zone, and converts it back to the system time with it datatyped as timestamptz.

> how are timestamps with timezones handled in comparison? It seems the zone is ignored and just the values are compared?

You aren't comparing timestamps with timezones.  You are comparing timestamps *without* timezones.

```
select pg_typeof(now() at time zone 'AEDT');
          pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
```

So yes, it ignores the timezones in your comparison, because they are no longer there anymore.